# How do I create a Caesar Cipher that shifts by 3 using a for loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am trying to create a Caesar cipher that permanently shifts by 3 and deals with the end of the array using modularisation. Currently, when I run the function it outputs the letters as undefined and I'm not entirely sure why.

```js
function caesarCipher() {
  let letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
  let shift = 3;
  let outputString = "";

  let userString = document.getElementById("input").value;

  for (count = 0; count < userString.length - 1; count++) {
    let character = userString[count];
    let letterIndex = letters[character];
    let newIndex = (letterIndex + shift) % 26;
    let newCharacter = letters[newIndex];
    outputString = outputString + newCharacter;
  }

  document.getElementById("output").value = outputString;
}
```

```html
<div id="alignment">
  <label for="input">String Input</label>
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Unciphered">
  <input type="submit" id="button" value="CIPHER STRING" onclick="caesarCipher()">
  <label for="input">String Output</label>
  <input type="text" id="output" placeholder="Ciphered">
</div>
```

Comment: So how is `let letterIndex = letters[character];` supposed to work? You are looking for "A" of an array? The code is expecting a numeric index of the array.

Comment: You can easily debug this step by step. For example `letters[character]` makes no sense because character is a letter not an index. `letterIndex + shift` also doesn't scan. `letterIndex` is a letter, and `shift` is a number. You end up with something like `A3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking for the index. If you entered "A" You are looking for `letters["A"]`. The array code is not going to find the index with A in it. You need to use indexOf to find it. You are also not looping through the whole array because of the -1 in the length check.

```js
function caesarCipher() {
  let letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
  let shift = 3;
  let outputString = "";

  let userString = document.getElementById("input").value;

  for (count = 0; count < userString.length; count++) {
    const character = userString[count];
    const letterIndex = letters.indexOf(character);
    const newIndex = (letterIndex + shift) % 26;
    const newCharacter = letters[newIndex];
    outputString = outputString + newCharacter;
  }

  document.getElementById("output").value = outputString;
}
```

```html
<div id="alignment">
  <label for="input">String Input</label>
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Unciphered">
  <input type="submit" id="button" value="CIPHER STRING" onclick="caesarCipher()">
  <label for="input">String Output</label>
  <input type="text" id="output" placeholder="Ciphered">
</div>
```

Comment: The output isn't a cipher shift. `abc` gives `CCC`.

Comment: @Andy All I did was fix the code so it ran, I did not fix the code to make sure it is uppercase. `ABC` gives a result. You get CCC because -1 + 3 is C

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this simple script will help. Just insert it in your file.

```js
function rot3(str) {
  let regex = /[\W]/g
  return str.split('').map(i => regex.test(i)
  ? i
  : String.fromCharCode(i.charCodeAt() + 3 > 90 
    ? (i.charCodeAt() + 3 - 26) 
    : i.charCodeAt() + 3)
  ).join("")
}

console.log(rot3("COBB"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).